# GCP equivalent of aws describe-network-interfaces. A way to see all networking resources in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2, gcloud, aws-cli

To debug IPs and search objects by name, the aws command of `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces` was very useful.

Is there anything similar to this in GCP?

Also you could run a script e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
vpc="vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
aws ec2 describe-internet-gateways --filters 'Name=attachment.vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep InternetGatewayId
aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep SubnetId
aws ec2 describe-route-tables --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep RouteTableId
aws ec2 describe-network-acls --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep NetworkAclId
aws ec2 describe-vpc-peering-connections --filters 'Name=requester-vpc-info.vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep VpcPeeringConnectionId
aws ec2 describe-vpc-endpoints --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep VpcEndpointId
aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --filter 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep NatGatewayId
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep GroupId
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep InstanceId
aws ec2 describe-vpn-connections --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep VpnConnectionId
aws ec2 describe-vpn-gateways --filters 'Name=attachment.vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep VpnGatewayId
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters 'Name=vpc-id,Values='$vpc | grep NetworkInterfaceId
```

Is there anything similar to this in GCP?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud has a similar CLI tool `gcloud` that has hundreds of commands.

AWS uses the command format `verb-service`.

Google Cloud has commands based on Google Cloud `service` `feature` `sub-feature` `verb`.

Examples:

- [gcloud compute networks](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks)
- [gcloud compute vpn-gateways](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/vpn-gateways)

Comment: I know of `gcloud`. Listing separate networks, health-checks, neg-s, backends, url maps etc is not what i'm looking for.

In comparison `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces` allows listing all IP-s & resource names (including all internal network interfaces used by aws internal networking abstractions) in use in your project.

My experience with `gcloud` so far would tell me that I would need to create a custom program with e.g. gcloud golang sdk to aggregate every network related abstraction 

Comment: @Paku Post a question with a specific problem with details and results. Right now you are speculating.